# How do I mount Ext4 using OS X Fuse

Tags: filesystem, unix

I installed `OS X Fuse` on OS X 10.9.4  as outlined in http://osxdaily.com/2014/03/20/mount-ext-linux-file-system-mac/

Unfortunately it does not mount any of my Linux filesystems (on external HD or SD card), either directly or with `Disk Utility`

Has anyone had any success with this? I note a few others seem to have similar problems.

Is any other package required?

NOTE I can read the data on a Linux machine, so do NOT want other suggestions, but it would be convenient to read on my Mac.

Comment: Did you also try it via Terminal as said here (https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/Ext/_history) under Useage. quote: "fuse-ext2 <device|image> <mountpoint> [-o option[,...]]"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Download and install FUSE-Ext2 as described [here](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/Ext) and then run something like

```
mkdir /Volumes/Linux
sudo mount -t fuse-ext2 /dev/disk2s6 /Volumes/Linux
```

You can figure out the device from looking at the output of `diskutil list`.

Comment: I had already done this, and it works. I really don't understand why, the `OS X Fuse` link seemed to imply it worked without, and I didn't want `ext2`.

Comment: I get this error.. "FUSE-EXT2 could not mount because the following problem occurred: dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libfuse.2.dylib Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/fuse-ext2 Reason: image not found" Anyone else facing this?

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out.. That was due to missing  compatibility layer. Reinstalled fuse to fix it

Comment: Can't install fuse-ext2 on latest Mac OS :(

Comment: On the latest Mac OS, you'll want to get fuse-ext2 from this fork that changes the install locations to be compatible with SIP: https://github.com/gpz500/fuse-ext2/releases/

Answer (score 13):

If you only want read support then [ext4fuse](https://github.com/gerard/ext4fuse) can do this job. If you already have homebrew then you can install it with:

```
brew install Caskroom/cask/osxfuse
brew install ext4fuse
```

after installation, simply run:

```
mkdir /Volumes/Linux
ext4fuse /dev/diskXsY /Volumes/Linux
```

where diskXsY can be found by entering the command `diskutil list`.

There is currently [no write support in ext4fuse](https://github.com/gerard/ext4fuse/wiki/Write-Support).

> ⚠️ **NOTE**: by default you'll only be able to mount and see your files with `sudo`. To mount as regular user add your user to the `operator` group with  **`sudo dscl . append /Groups/operator GroupMembership <your-user>`**. Once you've done this you will be able to mount as a regular user and see the files from Finder.

Comment: MacBook-Pro:~ myuser$ cd /Volumes/Linux 

-bash: cd: /Volumes/Linux: No such file or directory

...before i did sudo mkdir /Volumes/Linux ... sad day :(

Comment: It's weird, I'm also getting exactly this error :(

Comment: Ah I've figured out what's causing it! You need to make sure you're in a superuser environment other it just won't see it. Use `sudo su` and then try to `cd` into the directory again :D

Comment: Anybody figured out how to mount it with user permissions? Only works with sudo..

Comment: **IMPORTANT**: with ext4fuse by default you'll only be able to mount and see your files with sudo. To mount as regular user add your user to the `operator` group with  **`sudo dscl . append /Groups/operator GroupMembership <your-user>`**. Once you've done this you will be able to mount as a regular user and see the files from Finder.

Comment: @ccpizza That's helpful. I hope someone will put that info on the post

Comment: Found that `brew install ext4fuse` was failing 

This comment helped
https://github.com/gerard/ext4fuse/issues/66#issuecomment-819943409