# How to mount EXT4 disk on 10.15?

Tags: macos, filesystem, ext4

Since I have osxfuse installed it would be nice if I could use it. There are a [lot of](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73156/) (heavily) outdated [articles](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/140536/) here, saying that it is not [possible](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/128060/). Is this still the case?

Comment: I use Ubuntu in a virtual machine on my 2011 iMac. So accessing is a EXT4 disk is trivial for me. I start Ubuntu, mount the EXT4 disk, then share the disk with macOS. Both VirtualBox and Ubuntu are free products. I suppose the downside is this costs about 22 GB of space on my macOS volume for Ubuntu.

Comment: I agree with @DavidAnderson - lots of options here to read and write to EXT4 despite no native support in a stable and cost-efficient method.

Answer (score 22):

> **Update**: According to this [document in homebrew-core](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/64491) from November 2020, Homebrew maintainers no longer update or support macFUSE formulae, and Homebrew's continuous integration doesn't test them. macFUSE formulae will eventually be removed in the indeterminate future.
>
> Specifically, `ext4fuse` (mentioned below in the post) is disabled:
>
> ```
> brew install ext4fuse
> Error: ext4fuse has been disabled because it requires closed-source macFUSE!
> ```
>
> The reason for this is that FUSE for macOS does not have a license that is compatible with Homebrew.

Mac does not support ext4 file system. If you plug in a hard drive, Mac won't recognize it. Fortunately, there are several ways to handle this situation.

**1. Temporary options: Use VM**

Just install a version of Ubuntu, or whatever your Linux distribution of choice is, in a virtual machine host like VirtualBox, then mount the drive as you would any other and read away.

**2. Add ext4 support for macOS**

If you regularly use ext4 formatted drives and / or need to copy multiple files from there to the macOS drive, you need a better option.

You need to install [macFUSE](https://osxfuse.github.io/) (`osxfuse` has been succeeded by `macfuse` as of version 4.0.0) and `ext4fuse`. The easiest way to install `ext4fuse` is to use Homebrew. Note that `ext4fuse` us a read-only implementation of ext4 for FUSE to browse ext4 volumes and it cannot be used to write into ext4 volumes.

First, download and install macFUSE from their [releases page](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/releases) or install it using Homebrew.

```bash
brew install --cask macfuse
```

Then use Homebrew to install `ext4fuse`.

```bash
brew install ext4fuse
```

After installing the ext4 support software, you now need to determine the hard drive you want to mount. To do this, run the following command:

```bash
diskutil list
```

Save the partition ID (will look like `/dev/disk3s1`). Then, run the following command to mount the hard drive:

```bash
sudo ext4fuse /dev/disk3s1 ~/tmp/ext4_support_PARTITION -o allow_other
```

`ext4_support` above can be any name you choose. Now, navigate to the '/ tmp /' directory in the Finder and you will see the contents of the partition listed. If your drive has multiple partitions, you can mount them using the same steps as above. Just make sure to use different directory names to mount them.

**Update**

Attempting to install `ext4fuse` with brew results in an error. (See [issue #66 on GitHub](https://github.com/gerard/ext4fuse/issues/66)), so instead use the following commands to install it:

```bash
curl -s -o ext4fuse.rb https://gist.githubusercontent.com/n-stone/413e407c8fd73683e7e926e10e27dd4e/raw/12b463eb0be3421bdda5db8ef967bfafbaa915c5/ext4fuse.rb
brew install --formula --build-from-source ./ext4fuse.rb
rm ./ext4fuse.rb
```

**Warning**

Although these tools can help you read ext4 formatted hard drives, they are not stable. As long as you are mounting read-only drives, as what is being done in this solution, you will not have many risks. If you try to use these tools to *write* to an ext4 drive, you may lose data.

If you need to move files back and forth on a shared drive with Linux, this method is not recommended. Instead, use another file system like ExFAT or try the commercial option listed below

**3. Use Paid Software**

Software such as [Paragon](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/extfs-mac/) offers a free trial version, but to be safe, you should back up your hard drive first, in case there is a problem. If you want to buy software, it is available for 40$
**Note**: I haven't used this tool and can't say anything about what they have promised.

Although reading ext4 format on macOS is no longer an impossible task, it is frustrating when Apple does not support this format.

Try it on your own risk but I strongly recommend the first solution which is easy and convenient.

Comment: I got an error: Error: ext4fuse has been disabled because it requires closed-source macFUSE! What did I do wrong?

Comment: @ywiyogo : Unfortunately you did nothing wrong. ext4fuse has been removed from homebrew due to changes in the license. Read more here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/64491 . However, can install everything manually: https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/Ext

Comment: It looks like that this answer is adopted from [here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/mount-access-ext4-partition-mac/). If it is the case, it would be nice to refer to this source in your answer.

Comment: From this answer, it is unclear if I should install `macfuse` and then `ext4fuse`, or if `macfuse` replaces `ext4fuse`.

Comment: Using a temporary VM did the trick and keeps OS X clean. Nice solution.

Comment: The ext4fuse.rb link is dead

Comment: @Tiago take a look at this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/449025/493610

Answer (score 15):

For newer macs, e.g. Catalina, `brew install macfuse` instead of `brew install osxfuse` will work

Comment: This should be included in the correct answer.

Comment: what is the command of macfuse ? Tried both `macfuse` and `ext4fuse` but none worked

Answer (score 3):

With regards to the prior answer by @Udhy only the VM option has any chance of working but with a major caveat that it is VERY slow (I never got better than 30mb/sec).

Paragon simply does not work, refuses to mount any of my EXT4 disks.  Not sure why, maybe a Catalina issue?  However I'm not going to pay them so they can tell me we're SOL.

ext4fuse is a waste of time, it has not supported the last 3 versions of OSX so unless you're pre-Sierra this is not an option.  There's an open issue in the Github: https://github.com/gerard/ext4fuse/issues/36

It's five year's old and his last reply was 3 years ago, so don't get your hopes up.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I have been able to read/write ext4 is by using a virtual machine such as Virtual Box, running Linux (e.g., Linuxmint). It's odd that Paragon doesn't work in Catalina. Ext4fuse only gave me errors.