# Mount Ext4 on M1 or M1Pro or M1Max

Tags: mount, apple-silicon, ext4

I know this question has been asked many times. Everyone finds their own solution. I used to mount Ext4 via FUSE. But with the move to Big Sur I had to mount Ext4 using VirtualBox. But VirtualBox refuses to work with M1. I tried to do the same operation with QEMU. But I couldn't find anywhere guidance on how to integrate the disk connected to QEMU into Big Sur system. I would like to have the flash drive mounted automatically as soon as it is connected.

What is the easiest way to connect Ext4 to Macbook Air M1? Do I need to upgrade to a Macbook Pro M1Pro or M1Max? Maybe Apple has included support for the Ext4 driver in the Pro versions?

Comment: The change in processor won't make a difference - they run the same OS as other Apple Silicon

Comment: @mmmmmm Why is Apple unable to implement Ext4 support?  Couldn't Ext4 source code be open enough?

Comment: We have no idea why Apple does something. However in this case we know Apple does not support a much more common format NTFS why would they waste time on ext4

Comment: @mmmmmm NTFS is proprietary. Ext4fs is open source with a GNU license.

Comment: If you are willing to pay, then [Paragon](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/extfs-mac/) will sell you the software needed.

Comment: You could equally ask why Windows doesn't support it either. I'd expect the answer to be something along the lines of 'it's not worth the effort'

Comment: Note that even open source software is not free it has a cost. The cost is the time needed to write code to integrate it and to test that it works. Apple would get no worthwhile benefit for doing this work

Comment: I apologize for the hasty question before analyzing the problem. I found a solution in Paragon products.  It turns out that they have updated the series of software versions and now works with M1. I wonder how they did it? Because Big Sur doesn't support kext anymore.  Is there some way to extend kernel? If I knew of such a way, I would want to adapt the ext4 drivers to MacOS myself.

Comment: @DiD I think these articles are a good place to start: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/security/sec8e454101b/web, https://developer.apple.com/system-extensions/

If you have specific questions you should open a new question (potentially on another StackExchange depending on the subject)

Comment: @mmmmmm The change in processor does make a difference as VirtualBox is not supported on M1 (that's one of the techniques described for mounting ext4 on macOS)

Answer (score 11):

As long as `brew install ext4fuse` produces errors in the newest macOS system versions, I propose below workaround.
Tested on MacBook Air M2 with macOS Monterey.

#### Custom install

Create empty script file and open with code editor

```
nano ext4fuse.rb
```

Paste this code (Source: [Silicon related issue (66) from ext4fuse GitHub](https://github.com/gerard/ext4fuse/issues/66) ) and save script

```rb
class MacFuseRequirement < Requirement
  fatal true

  satisfy(build_env: false) { self.class.binary_mac_fuse_installed? }

  def self.binary_mac_fuse_installed?
    File.exist?("/usr/local/include/fuse/fuse.h") &&
      !File.symlink?("/usr/local/include/fuse")
  end

  env do
    ENV.append_path "PKG_CONFIG_PATH", HOMEBREW_LIBRARY/"Homebrew/os/mac/pkgconfig/fuse"
    ENV.append_path "PKG_CONFIG_PATH", "/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig"

    unless HOMEBREW_PREFIX.to_s == "/usr/local"
      ENV.append_path "HOMEBREW_LIBRARY_PATHS", "/usr/local/lib"
      ENV.append_path "HOMEBREW_INCLUDE_PATHS", "/usr/local/include/fuse"
    end
  end

  def message
    "macFUSE is required. Please run `brew install --cask macfuse` first."
  end
end

class Ext4fuse < Formula
  desc "Read-only implementation of ext4 for FUSE"
  homepage "https://github.com/gerard/ext4fuse"
  url "https://github.com/gerard/ext4fuse/archive/v0.1.3.tar.gz"
  sha256 "550f1e152c4de7d4ea517ee1c708f57bfebb0856281c508511419db45aa3ca9f"
  license "GPL-2.0"
  head "https://github.com/gerard/ext4fuse.git"

  bottle do
    sha256 cellar: :any, catalina:    "446dde5e84b058966ead0cde5e38e9411f465732527f6decfa1c0dcdbd4abbef"
    sha256 cellar: :any, mojave:      "88c4918bf5218f99295e539fe4499152edb3b60b6659e44ddd68b22359f512ae"
    sha256 cellar: :any, high_sierra: "fc69c8993afd0ffc16a73c9c036ca8f83c77ac2a19b3237f76f9ccee8b30bbc9"
    sha256 cellar: :any, sierra:      "fe8bbe7cd5362f00ff06ef750926bf349d60563c20b0ecf212778631c8912ba2"
    sha256 cellar: :any, el_capitan:  "291047c821b7b205d85be853fb005510c6ab01bd4c2a2193c192299b6f049d35"
    sha256 cellar: :any, yosemite:    "b11f564b7e7c08af0b0a3e9854973d39809bf2d8a56014f4882772b2f7307ac1"
  end

  depends_on "pkg-config" => :build

  on_macos do
    depends_on MacFuseRequirement => :build
  end

  on_linux do
    depends_on "libfuse"
  end

  def install
    system "make"
    bin.install "ext4fuse"
  end
end
```

Run below command from the `ext4fuse.rb` directory. Install `macFuse` and `ext4fuse`

```
brew install macFuse
brew install --formula --build-from-source ext4fuse.rb
```

#### Usage: `ext4fuse <disk> <mountpoint>`

Therefore, for ext4 device as e.g.`/dev/disk4s2`

```
sudo ext4fuse /dev/disk4s2 /Volumes/external_device -o allow_other
```

Volume is mounted, and you should be visible as:

- 'macFUSE Volume' when `shift+cmd+c` in Finder
- 'external_device' when `ls /Volumes`

If you would like to mount without sudo every time add macOS user to the operator group:

```
sudo dscl . append /Groups/operator GroupMembership <user>
```

Comment: `sudo umount /Volumes/external_device` to unmount it works great

Comment: Worked for me, Ventura 13.1.

Comment: I get `Partition doesn't contain EXT4 filesystem`, any help?

Comment: For the SD Card I formatted on my Steam Deck, the mount path is /dev/disk4s**1** - but thank you so much for this solution, where nothing else had worked (on MacOS Sonoma running on M1 Mac Mini).

Comment: @acmpo6ou run ```diskutil list``` and look for the line that says "Linux Filesystem".  That's the disk "**s**lice" you need to mount.   On my SD Card, it was on slice 1 of disk 4, so the path was: /dev/disk**4**s**1**